# Optimize Algorithm For Shut in Box Game

Tags: statistics, static-analysis

This game is a simplified version of Shut the Box. There are 9 tiles (1,2,3,4,5...9). The initial tiles are unflipped. You have 2 dices.
Each round, the player rolls the 2 dices and their sum is S.
After that, there are two options. The first option is to find the tile equal to S. 
If it is unflipped, you can flip it so that the tile becomes flipped up. 
The second option is to find two tiles that are unflipped such that the sum of the two tiles is S and flip them. You keep rolling the dice until one of the 2 situation happens:

1. If all 9 tiles are flipped at any time, the player wins.
2. If the player rolls a sum and cannot find any tiles to sum up to it
   or be equivalent to it, the player loses.

The problem is to simulate the game 100,000 times and improve the win percentage.

My current strategy is to check if S is unflipped and flip that. If a tile equal to S is not available, I try to find 2 tiles that equal to S, starting from the biggest available number. I'm thinking it's best to eliminate numbers like 9,8.. asap because the frequency of S being smaller than that is high.

Currently, my strategy has around a 5% win rate but it can apparently be optimized further to hit 10%. Are there anyways to optimize it further?

Comment: Keep trying more strategies?

Comment: "It can apparently be optimized further to hit 10%". How can it be **apparently** optimized? Can you add a reference to that claim?

Comment: Have you tried to determine the best strategy from the decision tree? It seems within reach by running a program within, say, a few months or even a few seconds.